# Trigger in Oracle SQL: When Timesheet is approved it should update the Payroll Table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

When the Table `Timesheet` is approved (`Timesheet_approved*` is Not Null) a trigger should fire which will calculate the payment for standard hours due (`Payroll_standard*`) and the payment due for any overtime (`Payroll_overtime* = standard hours X 1.5`) for the previous week on the table `Payroll`.

It should also calculate the pension contribution (`Payroll_pension* = 10% of standard + Over time`) due and then update the `payroll` table (working out what the next `payroll id` would be)

Please note `*` is used to point out the names of the table attributes. 
Tables being used/ affected are `Timesheet` and `Payroll`

So far I have the code below. However, I keep getting errors around bad variable bind:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -------------------------------------------------------------
32/3     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
33/3     PL/SQL: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or
     column specification

33/3     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.PAYROLL_STANDARD'
34/3     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.PAYROLL_OVERTIME'
35/3     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.PAYROLL_PENSION'
SQL>
```

SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_PAYROLLCALC
After UPDATE
on Timesheet FOR EACH ROW

Declare

V_TimesheetHRS number (3);
V_GRADEHRS number (3);
V_TimesheetOT number (3);
v_OTGRADEHRS number (3);
v_payrollID number (3);

BEGIN

SELECT Grade_rate into V_GRADEHRS
FROM Grade join Employee on (Emp_grade = grade_id)
where emp_ID = Timesheet_emp
;

SELECT Timesheet_hours into V_TimesheetHRS
From Funtom_timesheet join Funtom_employee on (emp_ID = Timesheet_emp)
where emp_ID = Timesheet_emp
;

Select Timesheet_OT into V_TimesheetOT
From Timesheet join Employee on (emp_ID = Timesheet_emp)
where emp_ID = Timesheet_emp
;

select Sum(Grade_rate * 1.5) into v_OTGRADEHRS
from Grade join Employee on (Emp_grade = grade_id)
where emp_ID = Timesheet_emp
;


IF Timesheet_approved IS NOT NULL then
    Update Payroll set
    :new.Payroll_standard := V_GRADEHRS * V_TimesheetHRS;
    :new.Payroll_overtime := v_OTGRADEHRS * V_TimesheetOT;
    :new.Payroll_pension  := ((V_GRADEHRS * V_TimesheetHRS)+(v_OTGRADEHRS * V_TimesheetOT));
END IF;

Select MAX(Payroll_id)+1 into v_payrollID
from Payroll;

:new.Payroll_id := v_payrollID;

END;
/
```

Notes:

- `Grade_rate` is the standard rate at which the worker is paid,
- `Grade_id` is the PK of that rate,
- `Emp_grade` is the FK that maps on to `Grade_id`,
- `Timesheet_emp` (FK) maps on to `emp_ID`,
- `Payroll_emp` (FK) maps on to `emp_ID`.

Comment: Looks like you need to the format the code a little more. BEGIN / END; / for example are coming through as text, node code.

Comment: how would you suggest i change BEGIN and END so that they are recognized as code?

Comment: Looks like someone has already done it for you.

Comment: You create 'code' in the edit box by laying out the text as you want it to appear (using spaces and not tabs), then select it all and hit the **`{}`** button above the edit box.  This indents everything by 4 spaces and the MarkDown formatting system interprets that as 'preformatted code'.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest not to write row level triggers for big business logic.

Row level triggers might have following problem

1. Trigger will execute for every row , it will be highly in-efficient and slow down the system.
2. Error handling will be cumbersome , if any one row- triggers has failed/error , then its fails sql update stm & difficult proceed.
3. very low chance of improving the performance , since trigger execute on row level.
4. Other developers could NOT find existence of a trigger .
5. Very difficult to enhance or debug later.
6. Triggers are difficult to test independently

implement in procedure
join table logically , don’t do row by row
have proper error handling procedure 
test procedure independently 
you have freedom of calling procedure any part of you code, may be during off peak hours.

Comment: 1. 1st and last sql can be combined 

SELECT Grade_rate into V_GRADEHRS ,Sum(Grade_rate * 1.5) into v_OTGRADEHRS
FROM Grade join Employee on (Emp_grade = grade_id)
where emp_ID = Timesheet_emp;

2. you might get mutation problem 
since your selecting  "From Timesheet" table inside the trigger

3. no error handling , what if this run time error is thrown from trigger 
what will happen to outer update query

Comment: Thank you Ramki for the suggestion however, it is specifically Trigger. That is what i have been asked to do other options have been mentioned but they have their heart set on a Trigger.